# Web scraping company details from LinkedIn --- not able to get body tag inside

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-scripting

I am trying to get company information from a LinkedIn account but I am not able to get any content inside body. Can you please tell me what is wrong?

I need to get

```
company 
website
industry
employes
etc.
```

but I am not able to. The only html I received is shown below:

Code:

```py
import requests

import webbrowser,html5lib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
linkdine_company_about=requests.get('https://www.linkedin.com/company/exxonmobil')
html=BeautifulSoup(linkdine_company_about.text,'html.parser')
print(html)
```

Run:

```html
<pre>
exxonmobil
https://www.linkedin.com/company/exxonmobil
      <html><head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function () {
          // Parse the tracking code from cookies.
          var trk = "bf";
          var trkInfo = "bf";
          var cookies = document.cookie.split("; ");
          for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i) {
              if ((cookies[i].indexOf("trkCode=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 8)) {
                  trk = cookies[i].substring(8);
              } else if ((cookies[i].indexOf("trkInfo=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 8)) {
                  trkInfo = cookies[i].substring(8);
              }
          }
          if (window.location.protocol == "http:") {
              // If "sl" cookie is set, redirect to https.
              for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i) {
                  if ((cookies[i].indexOf("sl=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 3)) {
                      window.location.href = "https:" +
                          window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
                      return;
                  }
              }
          }
          // Get the new domain. For international domains such as
          // fr.linkedin.com, we convert it to www.linkedin.com
          var domain = "www.linkedin.com";
          if (domain != location.host) {
              var subdomainIndex = location.host.indexOf(".linkedin");
              if (subdomainIndex != -1) {
                  domain = "www" + location.host.substring(subdomainIndex);
              }
          }
          window.location.href = "https://" + domain + "/authwall?trk=" + trk + "&trkInfo=" + trkInfo +
              "&originalReferer=" + document.referrer.substr(0, 200) +
              "&sessionRedirect=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
      }
    </script>
    </head></html>
***
Process finished with exit code 0
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to pass `headers`, Here you can do it.

> Do not forget to replace `Cookie` with your own.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'Host': 'www.linkedin.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cookie': '', # replace with your own cookies.
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'TE': 'Trailers'
}

r = requests.get(
    'https://www.linkedin.com/company/exxonmobil', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify)
```